# What mountain in NW USA is this?

Tags: usa, identify-this, mountains

So on a flight from YVR (Vancouver) to SLC (Salt Lake City), not far south of Vancouver - we'd just turned inland after flying down the coast, I saw this mountain.  I've gone through photos of Mt Rainier, Mt Adams and others but because of the different levels of snow it's hard to tell (taken at the end of August).

[image: photo of the mountain]

[image: another photo of the mountain]

Comment: Do you know what timezone your camera was set to? Then you can check the time stamp on the photos and use something like flightradar to check the location of that flight at the time, might narrow it down.

Comment: [Mt. Baker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mt_Baker), perhaps?

Comment: why NE in the title of your question? NorthEast? isn't it NorthWest USA over there?

Comment: @Vince: Yes, clearly that should be NW.  I edited.

Comment: why? Probably because I was half-asleep, lol.  Thanks for spotting that.  @Alendri - hmm, I'll have to check that, it was taken with my phone so should still have meta data.

Comment: yeah I think @Ansari could be right, because if we expect your plane was going southeast, the mountains in the background fit, the clouds are most likely over a mountain-free area and there could be a lake right after. Do you remember seeing a lake?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am fairly certain that this is [Mt. Adams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Adams_%28Washington%29), second-tallest mountain in Washington State. It is neither Mt. Rainier nor Mt. Baker, because both of those are heavier glaciated. The profile looks an awful lot of what I expect of Adams from the air (I climbed it a couple of times from the ground, and so have a reasonable mental picture, though of course distorted by ground-based perspective). As far as general shape goes, no other mountain in PNW area comes to mind.

Fun fact: Mt. Adams is the only volcano in Washington State with a non-technical route to the top. And because the South slope of the mountain is so moderate, once you do make it to the top, you can descend nearly three thousand feet with a series of simple sitting glissades (i.e. sliding on your butt down a chute established by many butts before you). Glissades require some experience with braking and control, but still you get to lose all that elevation in the space of ten minutes or so. It certainly makes for an exhilarating descent, and quick hike out.